# Why my facebook pixel don't fire on a meta-refresh-redirect page?

Tags: facebook, redirect, triggers, pixel, facebook-pixel

I am using a landing page that includes a submission form.

After the user enters his details and submits, I send him to a meta refresh redirect page, that redirects him to my product's page after 1 second.

I have installed Facebook pixel tracking on the redirect page, but for some reason, it's not firing when the user reaches it after he is submitting the form.

Here is the redirect page HTML code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '369855543698802');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  </script>
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=369855543698802&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/></noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; https://jvz4.com/c/617427/95609" />
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    fbq('track', 'Lead');
  </script>
  <p style="text-align:center; font-size:45px;">We are redirecting you to VideoMakerFX....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I set it to fire the lead event?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The event SDK loads asynchronously, it might simply not be available if you redirect after one second. You could just use the image version (what is currently wrapped in a noscript element), and hope that on its own loads faster, so that it would track correctly under these circumstances. (Whether using non-JS tracking all the time would skew any statistics in that regard, don’t know.)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is ok and should work. I make a poc myself with your code and the Lead is sent. But you can't see it with the Pixel Helper extension. To see it you must use the network pane of you browser's developer tools. I use Chrome DevTools.

@misorude is right about the redirect time. Facebook tags are pretty fast but you may loose a percentage of the hits with 1s redirect time.

Maybe you could form the pixel payload by yourself and use the [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) to send the request. Your redirect page could be something like this:

```html
<head>
  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    var id = '369855543698802';
    var hits = ['PageView', 'Lead'].map(function(event, index) {
      return 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=' + id + '&ev=' + event + '&dl=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&rl=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer) + '&ts=' + Date.now() + '&v=2.9.4' + '&r=stable&ec=' + index + '&fbp=' + document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)_fbp\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") + '&it=' + (Date.now() - 1000) + '&coo=false&rqm=GET';
    });
    hits.forEach(function(hit) {
      navigator.sendBeacon(hit);
    });
  </script>

  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; https://example.com" />

</head>

<body>
  <p style="text-align:center; font-size:45px;">We are redirecting you to example.com</p>
</body>

</html>
```